# Magmi import script stops

Tags: magento, magmi

I have the amazing script Magmi for Magento, however when I'm importing a large CSV, it seem to stop around the same place each time. I have tried running from browser and curl but get the same results.

I am importing 1 million products but it stops at 100,000ish or around 8-9 minutes of importing. I dont get any errors in the browser it just halts at 10%'ish. And in CURL it just exits.

If I run the import again to import only new, it will import up to around 200,000.

Any ideas? php mem limits 2gb, php max-execution timeout 3000000, apache timeout 3000000.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: did you try importing using magmi cli script and see what happens ?

Comment: Ah, it works fine in CLI. I can use this but would be handy to know what its not working the other ways. :)

Comment: It might be simply the "UI display" that breaks since the logfile may grow too much (currently UI runtime display is just a full reread & beautify of magmi logfile). Moreover, there might be other timeouts that occur in the web server. UI is "eye candy" for magmi, for serious stuff like 100k+ , cli is the best way to do thing.